# Tenant form in ABP framework

Tags: abp

**Tenant Management => Tenants**
When I click on the Tenants form, I am getting the below error. Took the source from the ABP-DEV. I am getting the same error when I click on the swagger,
api/multi-tenancy/tenants

```
{
```

"error": {
"code": null,
"message": "An internal error occurred during your request!",
"details": null,
"data": {
"ActivatorChain": "Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.TenantController -> Mop.Services.MopTenantAppService"
},
"validationErrors": null
}
}

I have added the below configuration in the application module which inherits AbpModule,

```
Configure<AbpMultiTenancyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.IsEnabled = true;
        });
```

In OnApplicationInitialization, given **app.UseMultiTenancy()**;

Do I miss any configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of ABP do you use ? which kind of template do you use ?